Angular: Loading Indicator Stuck When Using Promises in Parent-Child Component
I am working on an Angular app (version 17). I have a parent component with two child components. On my page, I want to ensure that the content won't be displayed until all the data (from both the parent and its child components) is ready. To achieve this, I decided to use promises so that the parent can listen to its children and wait until they are both ready. However, I noticed some strange behavior.
The issue I'm facing is that the loading indicator never stops, meaning isDataLoading remains true indefinitely. I'm not sure if I'm implementing the asynchronous logic correctly since I'm a bit new to handling promises. Could anyone take a look at my code and help me figure out what might be going wrong?
Parent component:
export class GeneralAnalyseComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(
    private commitService: CommitService,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  projectInfo: any | null = null;

  @Input() projectId!: number;
  @Input() selectedRepo: string | undefined;
  isDialogVisible: boolean = false;
  data: any;
  options: any;
  selectedSprint: { name: string; commitCount: number } | null = null;
  isProvided = false;
  isCommitLoading = true;
  isDataLoading = true;
  sprintDetails: any;

  // Pagination properties
  totalSprints: any[] = [];
  sprintLabels: string[] = [];
  itemsPerPage: number = 7;
  currentPage: number = 0;

  @ViewChild(PullRequestsComponent)
  pullRequestComponent!: PullRequestsComponent;

  
  @ViewChild(SuggestionsComponent)
  suggestionsComponent!:  SuggestionsComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProjectInfo();
    console.log(this.isDataLoading);
  }

  loadProjectInfo() {
    this.projectService.getProjectById(this.projectId).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.projectInfo = data;
        this.loadAllData();
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error fetching project info: ', err);
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['selectedRepo']) {
      this.loadAllData();
      console.log(this.isDataLoading);
    }
  }

  getCommitPerSprintPromise(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        this.projectInfo &&
        this.projectInfo.sprintStartDate &&
        this.projectInfo.sprintDuration &&
        this.selectedRepo
      ) {
        this.isProvided = true;
        this.isCommitLoading = true;
        this.commitService
          .getCommitsPerSprint(
            this.selectedRepo,
            new Date(this.projectInfo.sprintStartDate),
            this.projectInfo.sprintDuration
          )
          .subscribe({
            next: (data) => {
              this.totalSprints = data;
              this.totalSprints.forEach((sprint) => {
                console.log(sprint);
              });

              this.getLabels();
              this.updateChartData();
              this.isCommitLoading = false;
              resolve();
            },
            error: (err) => {
              console.error('Error fetching commits per sprint: ', err);
              this.isCommitLoading = false;
              reject(err);
            },
          });
      } else {
        this.isProvided = false;
        this.isCommitLoading = false;
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }

  loadAllData(): void {
    this.isDataLoading = true;

    const dataLoadingTasks: Promise<void>[] = [];

    if (this.pullRequestComponent) {
      dataLoadingTasks.push(this.pullRequestComponent.loadPullRequestData());
    } else {
      console.warn('PullRequestComponent is not defined.');
    }

 if (this.suggestionsComponent) {
      dataLoadingTasks.push(this.suggestionsComponent.getBranchAnalyses());
    } else {
      console.warn('SuggestionsComponent is not defined.');
    }

    dataLoadingTasks.push(this.getCommitPerSprintPromise());

    Promise.all(dataLoadingTasks)
      .then(() => {
        this.isDataLoading = false;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error loading data:', error);
        this.isDataLoading = false;
      });
  }


child components:

export class SuggestionsComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() selectedRepo!: string;
  messages: Message[] = [];
  plainMessages: string[] = [];
  suggLoading: boolean = false;
  pullRequestCommentsMessage: Message | null = null;
  timeReviewInfosMessage: Message | null = null;

  @Output() isSeggLoading = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private branchService: BranchAnalyseService) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['selectedRepo']) {
      console.log(this.selectedRepo);
      this.getBranchAnalyses();
    }
  }

  getBranchAnalyses(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.isSeggLoading.emit(true);

      this.suggLoading = true;
      this.messages = [];
      this.plainMessages = [];
      this.pullRequestCommentsMessage = null;
      this.timeReviewInfosMessage = null;
      console.log(this.selectedRepo);

      this.branchService.getBranchesAnalsye(this.selectedRepo, 4).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          // Store plain text branch analysis messages
          this.plainMessages = data.branchAnalysisResult.messages;

          // Store pull request comments message with links
          this.pullRequestCommentsMessage = this.formatPullRequestCommentsMessage(
            data.pullRequestCommentsInfosResponse
          );

          // Store time review information message with links
          this.timeReviewInfosMessage = this.formatTimeReviewInfosMessage(
            data.timeReviewInfosResponse
          );

          this.messages = this.plainMessages.map((message) =>
            this.formatMessage(message)
          );

          this.isSeggLoading.emit(false);
          this.suggLoading = false;
          resolve(); // Resolve the promise when done
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isSeggLoading.emit(false);
          this.suggLoading = false;
          // Note: You may not need to resolve here because the 'next' block already handles it
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching branch analyses:', error);
          this.isSeggLoading.emit(false);
          this.suggLoading = false;
          reject(error); // Reject the promise on error
        },
      });
    });
  }
}


second child component:


export class PullRequestsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input({ required: true }) repo!: string | undefined;
  @Input({ required: true }) sprintStartDate!: string;
  @Input({ required: true }) sprintDuration!: number;

  @Output() pullReqLoading = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  basicData: any;
  basicOptions: any;
  sprintData: any[] = [];
  currentPage: number = 0; // Start with the first page (0 index)
  rows: number = 1; // Display 1 sprint per page
  totalRecords: number = 0;

  noData = false;

  constructor(private githubService: GithubService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Default page:', this.currentPage);
    // Determine the default page based on sprint start date and duration
    console.log(this.repo);
    this.loadPullRequestData();
    this.initializeChartOptions();
    this.determineDefaultPage();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // Reload data whenever inputs change
    this.determineDefaultPage(); // Recalculate the default page if inputs change
    this.loadPullRequestData();
  }

  initializeChartOptions() {
    const documentStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
    const textColor = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--text-color');
    const textColorSecondary = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--text-color-secondary');
    const surfaceBorder = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--surface-border');

    this.basicOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      aspectRatio: 0.6,

      plugins: {
        legend: {
          labels: {
            color: textColor,
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: (context: any) => {
              const pr = this.sprintData[this.currentPage].pullRequestResponse[context.dataIndex];
              return [
                `Title: ${pr.title}`,
                `Message: ${pr.message}`,
                `Review Time: ${pr.timeReview.toFixed(2)} days`,
                `Total Comments: ${pr.totalCommentCount}`,
              ];
            },
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          position: 'left', // Left Y-axis
          ticks: {
            color: textColorSecondary,
          },
          grid: {
            color: surfaceBorder,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
        y1: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          position: 'right', // Right Y-axis
          ticks: {
            color: textColorSecondary,
          },
          grid: {
            color: surfaceBorder,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
        x: {
          ticks: {
            color: textColorSecondary,
          },
          grid: {
            color: surfaceBorder,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }

  determineDefaultPage() {
    const sprintStart = new Date(this.sprintStartDate);
    console.log('Sprint start date:', sprintStart);

    const now = new Date();
    const diffInMs = now.getTime() - sprintStart.getTime();
    const diffInWeeks = Math.floor(diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    console.log('Current week difference:', diffInWeeks);

    if (diffInWeeks >= 0 && diffInWeeks < this.sprintDuration) {
      this.currentPage = diffInWeeks;
    } else {
      console.warn('Current date is outside of the sprint range');
    }

    this.loadPullRequestData();
  }

  loadPullRequestData(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.pullReqLoading.emit(true);

      this.githubService
        .getPullRequests(
          this.repo!,
          new Date(this.sprintStartDate),
          this.sprintDuration
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.sprintData = data.sprintData;
            this.totalRecords = this.sprintData.length;

            this.noData = this.totalRecords === 0;

            // Ensure the currentPage does not exceed the available data
            if (this.currentPage >= this.totalRecords) {
              this.currentPage = this.totalRecords - 1;
            }

            this.basicData = this.buildChartData();

            resolve();
            this.pullReqLoading.emit(false);
          },
          complete: () => {
            this.pullReqLoading.emit(false);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching pull requests:', error);
            this.pullReqLoading.emit(false);
            reject(error);
          },
        });
    });
  }

  buildChartData() {
    const sprint = this.sprintData[this.currentPage];
    console.log('Sprint data:', sprint);

    const labels = sprint.pullRequestResponse.map(
      (pr: { title: any }) => pr.title
    );

    const totalCommentsData = sprint.pullRequestResponse.map(
      (pr: { totalCommentCount: any }) => pr.totalCommentCount
    );

    const reviewTimesData = sprint.pullRequestResponse.map(
      (pr: { timeReview: number }) => pr.timeReview
    );

    return {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Total Comments',
          data: totalCommentsData,
          borderColor: '#42A5F5',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(66,165,245,0.2)',
          yAxisID: 'y',
        },
        {
          label: 'Review Time (days)',
          data: reviewTimesData,
          borderColor: '#FFA726',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,167,38,0.2)',
          yAxisID: 'y1',
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}


The code you wrote is ... bad ... sorry but you said your are new in async coding :) you need to under stand more in detail how observables, promises and change detection in angular work. First could you please check, if isDataLoading is really true. If you work with async stuff it could be hard for the framework to check if there is a change

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to ensure that the page content won't load until all the data from both the parent and the childs is ready , if my code is that bad can anyone tell me how we normally handle this ??
